What should one do if wife is disobedient?
What should a man do if wife is disobedient according to smritis and puranas.
Should he abandon her.

I suggest you get a divorce, unless you wish to convert.

What do smritis and puranas say about how to deal with a disobedient wife?

I am not interested to convert

good I would suggest you separate, these religious differences lead to messy interactions later down the road.

But what do shastras say?

Shastras generally state a wife should be submisive and a king should banish all non-religious members or have them pay a fine if they insult our devtas.

But, also you need to mold yourself into the idealized man as stated in shastras. You cannot just be like a dictator or abusive overlord after all. Shastras advice a man not to be quarrelesome to wife and family.

Please give scriptural references
